# coordinatorLayoutStyle

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

I use coordinatorLayout with some widgets, and this rendering error appears:

> Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme.

Why have I this error?

Layout file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/ma_appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ma_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.popup"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/main_activity_recycler"/>



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ma_fab"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/ma_recyclerView"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/pencil"
    android:elevation="8dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: what is there  inside AppTheme.popup?

Comment: only 2 item textColor and background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line into the application theme :

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```